# Lag not working correctly on an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lag

I'm using Base R 4.2.1 and have a strange problem with lagging a column.

My dataframe has two columns, one for time and the other for the yield of a bond

```
df_bond <- data. Frame(t  = seq(0, 10, 1),
                      y_t = seq(.1, 0, -.01)
                     )
> df_bond
    t  y_t
1   0 0.10
2   1 0.09
3   2 0.08
4   3 0.07
5   4 0.06
6   5 0.05
7   6 0.04
8   7 0.03
9   8 0.02
10  9 0.01
11 10 0.00
```

I then add a column for price, and it works like a charm:

```
> df_bond$p_t <- 100 / (1 + df_bond$y_t)^(10 - df_bond$t)
> df_bond
    t  y_t       p_t
1   0 0.10  38.55433
2   1 0.09  46.04278
3   2 0.08  54.02689
4   3 0.07  62.27497
5   4 0.06  70.49605
6   5 0.05  78.35262
7   6 0.04  85.48042
8   7 0.03  91.51417
9   8 0.02  96.11688
10  9 0.01  99.00990
11 10 0.00 100.00000
```

But if I now add a column for return, I get something weird:

```
> df_bond$r_prior_yr <- df_bond$p_t / lag(df_bond$p_t, 1)
> df_bond
    t  y_t       p_t r_prior_yr
1   0 0.10  38.55433          1
2   1 0.09  46.04278          1
3   2 0.08  54.02689          1
4   3 0.07  62.27497          1
5   4 0.06  70.49605          1
6   5 0.05  78.35262          1
7   6 0.04  85.48042          1
8   7 0.03  91.51417          1
9   8 0.02  96.11688          1
10  9 0.01  99.00990          1
11 10 0.00 100.00000          1
```

Doing the division without the assignment shows that it is picking up a time series attribute, but I can't for the life of me explain why the ratio is always 1.

```
> df_bond$p_t / lag(df_bond$p_t, 1)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"tsp")
[1]  0 10  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `dplyr::lag`

```r
df_bond <- data.frame(t  = seq(0, 10, 1),
                       y_t = seq(.1, 0, -.01)
)
df_bond$p_t <- 100 / (1 + df_bond$y_t)^(10 - df_bond$t)
df_bond$r_prior_yr <- df_bond$p_t / dplyr::lag(df_bond$p_t, 1)
df_bond
#>     t  y_t       p_t r_prior_yr
#> 1   0 0.10  38.55433         NA
#> 2   1 0.09  46.04278   1.194231
#> 3   2 0.08  54.02689   1.173406
#> 4   3 0.07  62.27497   1.152666
#> 5   4 0.06  70.49605   1.132013
#> 6   5 0.05  78.35262   1.111447
#> 7   6 0.04  85.48042   1.090971
#> 8   7 0.03  91.51417   1.070586
#> 9   8 0.02  96.11688   1.050295
#> 10  9 0.01  99.00990   1.030099
#> 11 10 0.00 100.00000   1.010000
```

Comment: You are absolutely right - I tried it right away and this does work, but was so sure that base R had a lag function that I didn't bother loading dplyr initiallly. In addition, no error messages were raised - I need to understand the base R lag function.

Comment: @ThomasPhilips The base R `lag` function works on time series objects, which are numeric vectors with an attribute called `tsp`, which includes the start time, end time and frequency that the observations in the vector represent. Using base R's lag (`stats::lag`) only changes the tsp attribute, _not the vector itself_, so it won't allow you to lag a data frame column the way that `dplyr::lag` will. Of course, you could define your own simple lag with `lag <- function(x, n = 1) c(rep(NA, n), head(x, -n))` which does the same thing without adding a package dependency.

Comment: Thank you very much - that is very clear. This is the first time I have seen the `tsp` attribute, and didn't know what to make of it, as I am not working with a time series. I'll read the docs carefully, and it's complete overkill to define my own lag, but I will keep `stats::lag` vs. `dplyr::lag` in mind going forward.

Comment: @AllanCameron: the base R `lag` function is a S3 generic. The default method works on 'ts' objects. Many other classes define `lag` methods (e.g. zoo, xts). `dplyr::lag` breaks S3 method dispatch. Once's dplyr is loaded, any calls to `lag()` will not dispatch to any method, regardless of the object passed to it.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich sure - you'll notice I used `dplyr::lag` explicitly without loading `dplyr`, partly for this reason. There are some `lag` methods available in other packages, but the OP was looking for a simple lag of a numeric vector here and it didn't seem like the right time to start discussing S3 dispatch. Still, a valid point and thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @AllanCameron: Understood. I wasn't sure how aware you were of the details, so I thought I'd comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using the lag function from dplyr should get the result you're looking for. By default I suspect this is stats::lag causing your issue.

```
   df_bond <- data.frame(t  = seq(0, 10, 1),
                           y_t = seq(.1, 0, -.01))
    df_bond$p_t <- 100 / (1 + df_bond$y_t)^(10 - df_bond$t)
    df_bond$r_prior_yr <- df_bond$p_t / dplyr::lag(df_bond$p_t, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`stats::lag` mus be used over time series to give your expected result. Thus, modify your code as follows:
This do not need `dplyr`.

**NOTE:** `dplyr::lag` masks the base `stats::lag` function, thus if you will to use this solution, with dplyr loaded, you must use the fully qualified `stats::lag` instead of `lag`

```r
df_bond <- data.frame(t = ts(seq(0, 10, 1)),
                      y_t = ts(seq(.1, 0, -.01)))

df_bond$p_t <- 100 / (1 + df_bond$y_t)^(10 - df_bond$t)

df_bond[2:nrow(df_bond),"r_prior_yr"] <- df_bond$p_t / lag(df_bond$p_t, 1)

df_bond
#>     t  y_t       p_t r_prior_yr
#> 1   0 0.10  38.55433         NA
#> 2   1 0.09  46.04278  0.8373589
#> 3   2 0.08  54.02689  0.8522197
#> 4   3 0.07  62.27497  0.8675538
#> 5   4 0.06  70.49605  0.8833824
#> 6   5 0.05  78.35262  0.8997281
#> 7   6 0.04  85.48042  0.9166148
#> 8   7 0.03  91.51417  0.9340676
#> 9   8 0.02  96.11688  0.9521134
#> 10  9 0.01  99.00990  0.9707805
#> 11 10 0.00 100.00000  0.9900990
```

Comment: Note that `lag` isn't actually doing anything here. You are lagging manually by writing to `df_bond[2:nrow(df_bond),"r_prior_yr"]`

Comment: Don't agree. Here, `lag` sets the start time attribute of the `ts` object one step behind. i. e. if start==1, `stats::lag` sets attribute start to "0". If operands of the division are `ts` objects, `stats:::Ops.ts` is called (as division is a generic), which do the lag operation before sending the modified operands to the nextMethod default division. But unlike `dplyr::lag`, `stats::lag` drops  the unmatched head/tail elements instead of setting'em NA, hence i need to use 2:nrow(df_bond).

Comment: Yes, but this isn't a ts object, and doesn't need converted to one, and you get the same result if you do `<- df_bond$p_t / df_bond$p_t` instead of `<- df_bond$p_t / lag(df_bond$p_t, 1)` in the last line. So I can't see why you would use `lag` at all here.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate p_t, convert to zoo, use zoo's diff with arith = FALSE to get the ratio and convert back.  If a zoo object is ok then the last line can be omitted.

```
library(zoo)

df_bond |>
  transform(p_t = 100 / (1 + y_t)^(10 - t)) |>
  read.zoo() |>
  transform(r_prior_year = diff(p_t, arith = FALSE, na.pad = TRUE)) |>
  fortify.zoo(name = "t")
```

giving:

```
    t  y_t       p_t r_prior_year
1   0 0.10  38.55433           NA
2   1 0.09  46.04278     1.194231
3   2 0.08  54.02689     1.173406
4   3 0.07  62.27497     1.152666
5   4 0.06  70.49605     1.132013
6   5 0.05  78.35262     1.111447
7   6 0.04  85.48042     1.090971
8   7 0.03  91.51417     1.070586
9   8 0.02  96.11688     1.050295
10  9 0.01  99.00990     1.030099
11 10 0.00 100.00000     1.010000
```